# Golang: Is it possible to configure dlv to run in a path different from my application?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger, dlv

I'm working on a CLI system and would like to know how I can run the dlv in a different path than my application, in order to be able to debug some issues. It is possible?

I've already tried to perform some configurations within the vscode debug tool.
I hope I can run the debug within this tool.

Comment: What do you mean by run it in a different path? What did you try and what issues did you have?